# What characters uses base64encode?

Tags: php, html, base64

I refer to the base64 encode function like seen [here](http://php.net/base64_encode)

It might sound stupid but which characters does this use??

I know letter, digits and 've seen also the equal-sign (=). But i search for a 100% definition.

I need this because i use a base_64 encoded string in supposed-to-be valid html as an attribute and want to avoid conflicts.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default character set of the [Base 64 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) is `A`–`Z` (0–25), `a`–`z` (26–51), `0`–`9` (52–61), `+` (62), and `/` (63). The `=` is used as padding character to fill the value up to a length of a multiple of 24 bits.

There are also alternative character sets like [one that is safe to be used in URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5). But you could also use any other character set.

Comment: so i will additionally replace "+","/" and "=" to avoid conflicts with older browsers that don't support HTML5 yet?

Comment: @Email How do you use that Base 64 value in HTML?

Comment: as the "name" attribute in input type. i know bad practice but i have to ... temporarily.

Comment: @Email That should work fine as long as you quote the attribute value properly.

Answer (score 1):

Base 64 encoding uses `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `+` and `/` in many implementations.

There may also be trailing `=` characters to denote padding.